# How to handle CTRL+click in javascript

Tags: javascript, click

Let I've the `<a href="/link/">` tag. How can I the following handle: When the `CTRL` key is pressed we're left clicked to the `<a href="/link/">` tag I want to run an appropriate function which I'll specified as handler of this event. How to do that? I want to do this with **pure JS**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="#test" onclick="if(event.ctrlKey) alert('test');">test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can also recommened the Jquery way.

```
$('#element').click(function(e)
    {
        if (e.ctrlKey)
        {
            do_something();
        }
    });
```

May be seems a bit less simple, but I guess it gives you more options aswell.